# PyCharm Terminal Error

Tags: python, unix, pycharm, zsh, miniconda

I changed my shell from bash to zsh and now my PyCharm won't let me activate envs. I'm also using the zsh spaceship theme if that helps.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, updating to the latest version fixed it. Although I had to create a new project. So lessons learn't:
1. Change your shell
2. Then install PyCharm